# Need help this data in php

Tags: php

I'm using simple machines forum software and i need to add this code into the index.template.php file.

```html
echo '
<ins class='dp a3229' data-options='{"width":"728","height":"90","color_title":"eeeeee","color_desc":"4e88ce","color_border":"cccccc","effect":"random","fallback":"pub-3009185058478899^8943350103","notice":"7"}'></ins>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="//x.dpstatic.com/ad.js"></script>';
```

Doing it like the above just gives me a template parse error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
echo '
<ins class=\'dp a3229\' data-options=\'{"width":"728","height":"90","color_title":"eeeeee","color_desc":"4e88ce","color_border":"cccccc","effect":"random","fallback":"pub-3009185058478899^8943350103","notice":"7"}\'></ins>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="//x.dpstatic.com/ad.js"></script>';
```

here I escape all single quote  by adding back-slash '\' before it

Answer (score 0):

You're using single quotes inside single quotes, which gives a parse error. Try to escape (`'` -> `\'`) the single quotes inside the code you want to `echo`.